# Read function imported from kernel32.dll in pe on win64

Tags: portable-executable, win64

I try to read functions imported from kernel32.dll in pe on win64.It seems that an zero filled IMAGE_THUNK_DATA is the end of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA array.But i found that in kernel32.dll's IMAGE_THUNK_DATA array the second IMAGE_THUNK_DATA is 0 filled.Does it mean there is only one imported function from kernel32? Or how to get the size of IMAGE_THUNK_DATA array?

Comment: it mean only that you make some error

Answer (score 1):

[An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, Part 2:](https://web.archive.org/web/20090202093121/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx)

> Each IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR typically points to two essentially
> identical arrays. These arrays have been called by several names, but
> the two most common names are the Import Address Table (IAT) and the
> Import Name Table (INT).
>
> ...
>
> Both arrays have elements of type IMAGE_THUNK_DATA, which is a
> pointer-sized union. Each IMAGE_THUNK_DATA element corresponds to one
> imported function from the executable. The ends of both arrays are
> indicated by an IMAGE_THUNK_DATA element with a value of zero.